# Ember naming for parent/child objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to understand how naming works for parent/child objects in EmberJS.

Say I have 2 controllers as below;

```
// controllers/flash-messages.js
// controllers/posts/view.js
```

Now if I want to access "flash-messages" controller inside my "view" controller, 
I can just write the below in my controllers/posts/view.js

```
needs: ['flash-message'],
```

However, now assume I have one more controller as below (in sub-folder)

```
// controllers/posts/flash-messages.js
```

Now how do I distinguish between the 2 "flash-messages" controller ?
Is there any way by which I can refer to each of them uniquely ?

Also does the same concept apply to models & routes ?

Comment: needs: ['flash-message', 'posts/flash-messages]. Does this not work? :D

Comment: Views and controllers aren't going to be a part of Ember for much longer. If you are just starting a project, I recommend looking into Ember 2.0 and Ember CLI sooner than later. : )

Comment: yes i am starting out with Ember v1.13..though i do not intend to use Views, I do use controllers mainly for binding with the templates...Not sure where they can go otherwise..

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your controllers like this:

```
messages: Ember.inject.controller('flash-messages'),
postMessages: Ember.inject.controller('posts/flash-messages'),
```

Comment: Thx a lot...What about routes or models with same names ? Can they be accessed in a similar way ?

Comment: No. If you're using ember-data, you can access models from pretty much anywhere via `this.store`, but typically you only do so in a route. And you can't access routes (and I can't imagine why you would need to).